# What is the term for esoteric exegesis (of the Jewish texts) in Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew

Is there like a nice one-word term to use when describing any estoeric reading/exegesis of any Jewish text, but specifically the Tanakh and the Oral Torah?

I think that there should be at least some specific term for this from the Kabbalah but I'm not sure what it is.

EDIT: The context/purpose of such "estoeric exegesis" is to resolve apparent "contradictions" in the text.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @shmosel I have no example. I am only talking in generalities here.

Comment: @shmosel What kind of example would you want for this?

Comment: Perhaps Drash? Remez?

Comment: [Sod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardes_%28exegesis%29#Sod), if anything.

Comment: @shmosel Yeah, its probably Sod (סוֹד‎), thank you

Comment: @shmosel I think that's the term. If you want to write it out as a proper answer, go ahead and I will choose it as the answer

Comment: It's up for grabs.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109445/21 ?

Comment: @Shalom That's only for resolving contradictions, but it doesn't necessarily have to be through esoteric exegesis so it doesn't count for this. The focus is the word for "esoteric exegesis" but the context of this esoteric exegesis is to resolve contradictions (for the sake of the question).

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is "סוד", or "secret."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/49937)

Comment: @sabbahillel read the comments on the question. The questioner agreed that this is a good answer.